# Problems with Netbeans 7.3.1 with maven project

Tags: jboss7.x, netbeans-7

I'm new novice with Netbeans but I'm enjoying it, I have only two question about this IDE, Somebody help me?

- Is it possible to show the server log (JBoss AS 7) when I run the project? The Glassfish's log open OK but not OK with JBoss I need to open manualy
- I created a maven project and opened in NB, the save and compile not working for me, I tried every options in the property of the project but when I change something in the project I need to execute F11(compile) or F6(run) to compile and deploy on server, Is it correct? In my opinion NB should this for me.

I'm using 7.3.1 NB

Thanks guys!!!